# How to write a condition for float value?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ios-simulator

Hi im working with sqlite.
 stringFloat1 = [pediDetails.doseTo FloatValue];

```
float mulWith1 = [appDelegate.selectedWeight FloatValue];

NSLog(@"mulwith1:%f",mulWith1);
//if(mulWith1 =0.00) {
//  int temp1=0;
//}
//  else {

float temp1 = stringFloat1*mulWith1;
NSString *setWeight;
NSLog(@"temp1:%f",temp1);
//  }
//float temp1;
//NSString *setWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",temp,temp1];

//if(temp1=0.00) {
//setWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",temp];
//}
//else{ 
setWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f-%.02f",temp,temp1];
```

What i need is,if temp1 is 0.00,then only temp value should be displayed.What is the condition?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if(temp1==0.00)
{
   setWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",temp];
}
```

Instead of

```
if(temp1=0.00)
{
  setWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",temp];
}
```

Comment: In the first if loop checks temp1 is equal to 0.00, in the second loop first assign temp1 to 0.00 then check if(temp1),ie which will be true if temp1 > 0.00

Comment: i cant find any change in the above two